# how to authenticate jhipster ionic login

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, session-cookies, jhipster

I am trying to create an **ionic** app, This app uses a **jhipster** created web-app as intranet with **HTTP session authentication**.
How should i authenticate user in ionic app who is already created in jhipster.

**JHipster configuration, a .yo-rc.json file generated in the root folder**

```
{
"generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
"baseName": "vconnect",
"packageName": "com.zenfact.vconnect",
"packageFolder": "com/zenfact/vconnect",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "session",
"hibernateCache": "ehcache",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "no",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "elasticsearch",
"buildTool": "maven",
"enableSocialSignIn": false,
"rememberMeKey": "559bbe3167552d040ba24d16506d389a7ba851c3",
"useSass": false,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
"gatling"
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "en",
"languages": [
"en",
"zh-cn",
"fr",
"hi",
"ja"
]
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging around and found that mobile apps are not a big fan of cookies.

Thus have decided to recreate the **jhipster** application to either **oauth** or **JWT**

Note:

1. Jhipster has 3 authentication method JWT, Oauth2 and HTTP session.
2. I initially started with a Jhipster project with HTTP session.
3. I was separately creating a ionic app project which was supposed to consume
   the rest call of this jhipster application.
4. Long story short after some trial and error I came to realization to just recreate the ionic app with either JWT or Oauth2 authentication.

Comment: can u provide more details on how you moved forward? Im not being able to find much.

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego I have added some more explanation in the answer. Let me know if you need anything specific. :D

Comment: @abhi314 I am using JWT and I can Sign In, but not Sign up. (The screen of sign up has only 1 password) Any clue?